# ASP.NET How to set Text to the right side of image

Tags: html, css, asp.net

I'm making a website, but I'm having a bit of a problem. I have an image and some text, but the text keeps getting under til image how do I set til text to the right side of the image?
[image]

Here are some of my code.

```
<img src="~/Images/Billede%20af%20mig.PNG" height="254px" width="200px" />

<section class="contact">
    <header>
        <h3>Telefon:</h3>
    </header>
    <p>
        <span class="label">Mobil nummer:</span>
        <span></span>
    </p>
</section>

<section class="contact">
    <header>
        <h3>E-mail:</h3>
    </header>
    <p>
        <span class="label">Spørgsmål:</span>
        <span><a href="mailto:info@mail.nu">Info@mail.nu</a></span>
    </p>
```

My CSS

```
    /* contact */
.contact h3 {
    font-size: 1.2em;
}

.contact p {
    margin: 5px 0 0 10px;
}

.contact iframe {
    border: 1px solid #333;
    margin: 5px 0 0 10px;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

put your contents in div and give styling to them

```
<div>
    <div style="float:left;">
        <img src="~/Images/Billede%20af%20mig.PNG" height="254px" width="200px" />
    </div>
    <div>
        <section class="contact">
            <header>
                 <h3>Telefon:</h3>

            </header>
            <p> <span class="label">Mobil nummer:</span>
 <span></span>

            </p>
        </section>
        <section class="contact">
            <header>
                 <h3>E-mail:</h3>

            </header>
            <p> <span class="label">Spørgsmål:</span>
 <span><a href="mailto:info@mail.nu">Info@mail.nu</a></span>

            </p>
        </section>
    </div>
</div>
```

have a look at this fiddle that i created

http://jsfiddle.net/yadUR/3/

Answer (score 1):

Create two divs and put the image in one Div and the text in the other, and set Divs style to float left and right, like this :

```
<div>
    <div style="float: left">
    <img src="~/Images/Billede%20af%20mig.PNG" height="254px" width="200px" />
    </div>

    <div style="float: right">
    <section class="contact">
        <header>
            <h3>Telefon:</h3>
        </header>
        <p>
            <span class="label">Mobil nummer:</span>
            <span></span>
        </p>
    </section>

    <section class="contact">
        <header>
            <h3>E-mail:</h3>
        </header>
        <p>
            <span class="label">Spørgsmål:</span>
            <span><a href="mailto:info@mail.nu">Info@mail.nu</a></span>
        </p>
     </div>
</div>
```

***OR*** Or if you use `<asp:Image />` Just set `Image.ImageAlign` Property on your `<img>`

`<asp:Image src="~/Images/Billede%20af%20mig.PNG" height="254px" width="200px" ImageAlign="Left"/>`

And the text will automatically wrap around image..

For more info check [Image.ImageAlign MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.image.imagealign%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: Thank you, that works aswell, but I will go with the other answer. But take my upvote I appreciate the help.